# Ubuntu 9.10 Live CD: Trying to restore by broken Grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub, repair, livecd

ello,

I am trying to fix my Grub on the live cd of ubuntu 9.10. (i have a backup in ./home/myuser/Desktop)

Now, i've got access to the ./home/myuser folder, but now it has two files: 'readme.txt' and 'access your private data'. When i open 'readme.txt' it tells me that for security reasons the folder has been unmounted, but when i click the 'access your private data' or hit 'ecryptfs-mount-private' in terminal it would be mounted.

So, i clicked on 'access your private data': nothing happened. When i typed in the terminal command, it gave me 'Encrypted private directory is not setup properly'.

What do i have to do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two files indicates that you have a encrypted home folder. Grub is not your problem.

Look at: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/03/mounting-your-encrypted-home-from.html

Comment: When i try to boot it says something that grub is no good any more and that it needs to be fixed. it just opens this 'grub rescue' but i dont know what to do there...

Comment: I think this is what you looking for: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-24113.html